# Address fields by country

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

The iPhone Contacts app has a nice interface for saving addresses. When you change the country, the fields change to be specific to that country's address fields. For example, the US has a "Zip" field, where other countries have a "Postal Code".

[image]

Is there any method to get these fields, possibly by passing a country code?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary` method of ABAddressFormatting class. Here is the link to the [ABAddressFormatting Class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/AddressBookUI_Functions/Reference/reference.html)